# openlayer 3 catch move end / zoom end events

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Is there any way to catch `moveend` and `zoomend` events in OpenLayers3?

Or is there a workaround to use `change:center` or `change:resolution` to know when the moving/zooming ended?

Answer (score 1):

I've searched the 
[documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html) for unstable features and found `moveend` as expermental in [ol.Map](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a moveend event on map object, but no zoomend event yet. You can create a zoomend event like [this](http://jongarrido.es/blog/2015/09/30/zoomend-event-in-openlayers-3/):

```
var currentZoomLevel;

function initZoomEndEvent()
{
    map.on('moveend', checknewzoom);
    $(document).on('zoomend', function () {

        console.log("Zoooom");
    })
}


function checknewzoom(evt)
{
    var newZoomLevel = map.getView().getZoom();
    if (newZoomLevel != currentZoomLevel)//
    {
        currentZoomLevel = newZoomLevel;
        $(document).trigger("zoomend", zoomend_event);
    }
}

function zoomend_event(evt)
{
    //Your code here
}
```